# Flex - give default cursor a dropShadow

Tags: apache-flex, cursor, styles, shadow

Topic.  Is there any way to do this on the default cursor?  (I haven't looked into it, but presumably it can be done on a custom cursor -- ??).

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just create a custom cursor like this

```
<mx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
   import mx.managers.CursorManagerPriority;
   import mx.managers.CursorManager;

   [Embed("/cursors/mycursor.png")]
   private var customCursor:Class;

   private function showCursor():void
   {
     CursorManager.setCursor(customCursor, CursorManagerPriority.HIGH, 3, 2);
   }

   private function removeCursor():void
   {
     CursorManager.removeAllCursors();
   }
 ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Hope this helps!